# How to get Long value from text field and send form into ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

How would I get a long data type in Java? 
For example, I would get a string like this:

```
String thisString = thisString.getText();
```

But I try the same with a long data type and it doesn't work.
I need it to send it to an ArrayList, and this is the whole code:

```
package dao;

import entities.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.text.*;
import javaapplication1.*;

public class ProductModel{

    public List<Product> findAll(){
        try {
            List<Product> forms = new ArrayList<Product>();
            JTextField textDate;
            JTextField textFecha;
            JTextField textTotal;
            return forms;
        } catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
   }
}
```

That's my array, and then I have this other file here:

```
public class Product{

   public String date;
   public String fac;
   public Long total;
}
```

And then finally, the button that sends the data that to the ArrayList:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Product form = new Product();
        form.date = textDate.getText();
        form.fac = textFac.getText();
        form.total = textTotal.getText();
        forms.add(form);
    }
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `String` is not a `Long`. That is the reason compiler is shouting on you. You need to parse it.

```
form.total = Long.parseLong(textTotal.getText());
```

Make sure you have a null check and assign it to 0 if the string is null.

And once you fix the issue, please give a read to [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Thanks a lot, another question (which is kind of related to what Im trying to do) is, I get an error: "forms" cannot be resolved in this line `forms.add(form);` and "forms" is the name of the ArrayList, any way to solve this?

Comment: @J.Doe Could you please ask that in another question ?